# Using ATR to set stop losses and take profit orders

Tags: pine-script

Trying to use ATR for stop and profit orders, but they don't seem to be triggering the orders correctly. For long trades I want the profit order to be 2*ATR + highest high from last 7 bars, and the stop loss to be lowest low from last 7 bars - ATR. And for Short selling just the inverse.
Here is the relevant part of the script.

```
LookBack = input(title="Stop/Profit LookBack", type=input.integer, defval=7, minval=1)
tplong = highest(high, LookBack) + (atr(14)*2)
stoplong = lowest(low, LookBack) - atr(14)
tpshort = lowest(low, LookBack) - (atr(14)*2)
stopshort = highest(high, LookBack) + atr(14)

strategy.entry("Long", true, when = buySignal, comment = "Buy")
strategy.exit("Close Long", "Long", limit = tplong, stop = stoplong, comment = "Close Long")
strategy.entry("Short", false, when = sellSignal, comment = "Sell Short")
strategy.exit("Close Short", "Short", limit = tpshort, stop = stopshort, comment = "Close Short")
```

It does not seem to be calculating the stop and limit orders correctly and I am lost as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LookBack = input(title="Stop/Profit LookBack", type=input.integer, defval=7, minval=1)

atr14 = atr(14)
float longSL = na
float longTP = na
float shortSL = na
float shortTP = na

longSL := buySignal ? lowest(low, LookBack) - atr14 : longSL[1]
longTP := buySignal ? highest(high, LookBack) + atr14*2 : longTP[1]
shortSL := sellSignal ? highest(high, LookBack) + atr14 : longSL[1]
shortTP := sellSignal ? lowest(low, LookBack) - atr14*2 : longTP[1]

strategy.entry("Long", true, when = buySignal, comment = "Buy")
strategy.exit("Close Long", "Long", limit = longTP, stop = longSL, comment = "Close Long")
strategy.entry("Short", false, when = sellSignal, comment = "Sell Short")
strategy.exit("Close Short", "Short", limit = shortTP, stop = shortSL, comment = "Close Short")
```